# which way is better in android , JobScheduler or use timer?

Tags: android, service, battery

I'm developing a chat application, For getting new messages in real-time we use a foreground service. (because of some situation we can't use FCM)
To be confident that clients are connected to the server, We send a ping to server every 1 minute with JobScheduler. Now we have a battery usage problem.
It's better to use CountDownTimer like bellow code in our foreground service :

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimerPingPeriodic;
public static boolean isPinging;

public void pingPeriodic(boolean fromService) {

    if (countDownTimerPingPeriodic != null) {
        countDownTimerPingPeriodic.cancel();
        countDownTimerPingPeriodic = null;
    }


    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long future = 75000;
            countDownTimerPingPeriodic =

                    new CountDownTimer(60000, 60000) {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long l) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            sendPing(false);
                            pingPeriodic(false);

                        }
                    };
            isPinging = true;
            countDownTimerPingPeriodic.start();

        }
    });

}
```

or it's better to use job service like bellow (Now we use bellow code and send ping in onStartJob):

```
public class ScheduleConnectionJob extends JobService {

private static final String TAG = "ScheduleConnectionJob";
private int i = 0;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

    //here I will send a ping to the server

    jobFinished(params, true);
    Util.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext()); // reschedule the job
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    Util.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Util.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext());
}}
```

And to call and repeat this service We use bellow code to repeat every 1 minute:

```
public class Util {

public static final long MinimumSchadulePeriodic = 15 *  60 * 1000 ;
// schedule the start of the service every 10 - 30 seconds
public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, ScheduleConnectionJob.class);

        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);

        FileLog.i("Util:",
                Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber() + " " +

                        "scheduleJob:scheduleJob");
        builder.setMinimumLatency(MinimumSchadulePeriodic); // wait at least
        builder.setOverrideDeadline(60 * 1000); // maximum delay

        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY); // require unmetered network

        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

        if (jobScheduler != null) {
            jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use WorkManager if it will be better in your case instead of JobScheduler.

The WorkManager API makes it easy to schedule deferrable, asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits or device restarts.

Checkout this official documentation for further information :: 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/

Also read this article https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-workmanager-2083bcfc4712

Answer (score 1):

If you don't support below SDK 14 you can use [workmanager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/). Otherwise see this [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/) to read about all the options.

Some extra resources on battery management: [Doze and standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby), [power management restrictions](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/power-details), [Analyzing power usage](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/battery-historian), [Excessive wake-ups](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/wakeup), [Excessive network usage in background](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/bg-network-usage)

Hope this helps you along a bit. I have to say that having your app ping the backend every minute seems a bit much. Unless its vital that your users receive their messages the instant they get send, it might be better to atleast bump that down to 5 or 10 minutes in background.